# i reset my password for xampp localhost and now i cant get on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am new to php and MySQL so this may have an obvious answer. I just reset my password and now when i go to phpmyadmin it will not allow me on saying: #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I know my new password but I don't know where to tell it so it will let me on. Specific instructions on how to tell it my new password would be highly appreciated because as I said I am new to this subject. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you flush the tables?

Comment: I don't think i flushed the tables. I did not put in code for that but if their is another way of doing it then i might have.

Comment: do you have any other ideas to how to put in a password. do i even need to put in my new password and if not what might be wrong.

Comment: Just run the query `flush tables;`

Comment: how do i run the query if i cant log onto phpmyadmin

Comment: From the MySQL command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the config file for phpmyadmin.

1. Open config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin directory
2. Find line 21: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''
3. Change it to: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';
4. Restart XAMPP

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1617399